# Hide a UITabBarControllers Tab

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on a new feature for my app.
I want to submit a bug fix update (unrelated to the new feature) and so I need to just hide the 1 tab.
Is there a way to do this in code so that I can easily hide the tab and bring it back when needed?

UPDATE:
Here's what I did

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[viewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1]; //remove the tab you don't need...
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
[viewControllers release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `viewControllers` property of your UITabBarController to not include the tab you'd like to hide, then setting it again to include that tab should do the trick.